# Using value of void pointers as keys in hash table

Tags: c, pointers, hash, standards

I need to implement a dictionary which uses arbitrary void pointers as keys.

In order to make accesses O(1), I would like to hash the values of the pointers themselves (not the data they point to).

So for example suppose I have a `void *key`, and I already have a generic hash function `unsigned int hash(const char *data, size_t len)`.

Is it correct to do something like `unsigned int keyhash = hash((char *)&key, sizeof key);` to calculate the hash value?

Additionally, in order to deal with collisions, I would then need to iterate over a linked list of all keys that hash to the same value. To do that, would the standard allow to compare `void *key1, *key2` as `key1 == key2;` or as `memcmp(&key1, &key2, sizeof (void *));`?

Comment: I think `sizeof key` is wrong. Because it is not the size of the content.

Comment: It is *unlikely* that `&key, sizeof key` are correct. It is *possible*, but I doubt it. Unless you're intentionally hashing the *values* of  `void` pointers (not what they point *to*, the actual addresses themselves), it is certainly wrong to do what you're proposing.

Comment: Yes, I intend to hash the values, not the data they point to.

Comment: Then, surprise, it is correct =P

Comment: `hash((char *)&key, sizeof key)` looks exactly right to me.

Comment: The reason is that I want to associate some metadata to certain structures that are allocated in memory. And I cannot append it to the structures themselves, because the data may be different for different contexts (and different threads).

Comment: And i'm not sure what the standard says about using `==` to compare pointers, if they don't necessarily point to the same array.

Comment: @TobErnack pointers can always be compared with `==`.

Comment: Also, can you show more code? Like the body of the `hash` function. We really don't know what you do with the `data`.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me but as far as I understand the question this part - `unsigned int keyhash = hash((char *)&key, sizeof key);` - is wrong. I don't think you shall do `&key` as you don't want the address of the void pointer. You want the value so just use `key`, i.e. no `&` BTW: comparing two void pointers using `==` is fine.

Comment: You can consider converting the `void *` values to `uintptr_t` because comparisons between `uintptr_t` (unsigned integer) values are fully defined, even if the comparisons between the `void *` values are not.  Theoretically, you could have a system without a `uintptr_t` type.  More pragmatically, there are systems where function pointers are too big to fit into any object pointer (IBM AS/400 and successors).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, you want to hash on the **value** of the void pointer. In that case this code

> unsigned int keyhash = hash((char *)&key, sizeof key);

is wrong as you pass the address of the void pointer (i.e. &key) instead of the value (i.e. just key).

Take a look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int hash(const char *data, size_t len)
{
    // Dummy code ... just a print - no hash calculation
    printf("value of data %p with size %zu\n", (void*)data, len);
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    void* key;
    key = malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("value of key %p\n", key);

    // First call using &key
    unsigned int keyhash1 = hash((char *)&key, sizeof key);

    // Second call using key (i.e. no &)
    unsigned int keyhash2 = hash((char *)key, sizeof key);

    free(key);

    return 0;
}
```

The output can be:

```
value of key 0x2b51dca5a010
value of data 0x7fffff6be5e8 with size 8
value of data 0x2b51dca5a010 with size 8
```

As you can see the first function call doesn't get the value of the pointer to the malloced object, i.e. the first call is wrong. The second function call gets the correct value.

So don't us `&key` - jus `key`

BTW: Comparing  two void pointers using `==` is fine.

Comment: OP has said he wants to use pointers as hash keys, not pointer targets. Using `&key` is correct for that use.

Comment: @nos OP says he wants to use the pointer value as the key, not what is being pointed at by the pointer. So a hash that requires a (pointer, len) to the object to be hashed should be given a pointer-to-the-pointer (&key), instead of a pointer-to-the-object (key).

Comment: It all depends on the specific calling sequence of the `hash()` function.  But given that it seems to be passed a pointer *and a length*, it seems likely that the hash function is treating the pointer it's given as a pointer to the (variably-sized) data to be hashed.  If so, passing it a pointer of `&key` and a size of `sizeof(key)` seems correct.